# mPDF: Creating more pdf files in one script throws an error "Undefined offset: -1" in mpdf\src\CssManager.php

Tags: mpdf

This works:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html1);
$mpdf->Output("file1.pdf","F");
```

But I want to create two pdf files in one script.
This doesn't work:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html1);
$mpdf->Output("file1.pdf","F");
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html2);
$mpdf->Output("file2.pdf","F");
```

It throws an error "Undefined offset: -1"
in file: ... mpdf\src\CssManager.php

Do I have to reset it after first output? How?

Thank you.

Comment: Update:
Error is triggered by WriteHTML method. It's something about html parser. If there is a table with many rows (tr), it's a problem. May be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

Into mpdf/mpdf/src/CssManager.php insert before line 1510:

$this->tbCSSlvl = $this->tbCSSlvl==0 ? 1 : $this->tbCSSlvl; // BUG REPAIR